# Storing data without a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I made a small application (asp.net mvc) with a few pages of inputs, a review page and then generates a word doc that the user saves to their computer.

The app may have multiple users at the same time.

If I dont have access to a database, what is the best way to store the model data until the review page and the word document is generated?

Currently, I use Tempdata and it works but something tells me this is not the right way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Session. [Storing models in Session](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Store-Model-in-Session-and-display-in-View-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Using of it is just like the TempData. You can assign a model to a Session like this:

```
public class Model {
    public int x { get; set;}
    }

Model model = new Model();
model.x = 1;

Session["Model"] = model;
```